# PHP PDO dynamically updating db table with multiple records to a specific user ID

Tags: pdo

/* Newbie need some help; I am creating a class to auto update my apps db record    when instructed to, but I am consistently getting this message below, and for the heck    of it, I just not seeing what I am doing wrong.  Can someone please look at my    codes for me?  Thank you.

Warning: PDOStatement::bindParam() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in……..on line 331; that where the "else if(is_string($val)){" is located.

*/

```
// vars given
     // DBDriver: MySQL
$myTable = 'seeYou';
$loginDate = NULL;
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];  
$date = @date('m/d/Y \a\\t h:i a');
$_id =1;

// data array 
$idata = array("last_logged_in"=>$loginDate,
             "login_date"=>$date,
             "ip_addr"=>$ip
             );


class name
{

    ///------------ other methods here---------///

/**
 *--------------------------------------------
 *  Method - PDO: SET FIELD VALUE PLACEHOLDER   
 *--------------------------------------------
 * @return fields with prefix as placeholder 
 */
protected function set_fieldValPlaceHolders(array $data) 
{
    $set = '';
    foreach($data as $field => $value)
    {
        $set .= $field .'= :'.$field . ','; 
    }

    // remove the last comma
    $set = substr($set, 0, -1);
    return $set;
}


public function save($data=NULL, $_id = NULL, $rows= NULL, $dbTable= NULL)
{
    //----------------- some other codes goes here ----------------//
    $id = (int)$_id;

        // update row with a specific id
        if (isset($id) !== NULL && $rows === NULL)
        {
            $set = $this->set_fieldValPlaceHolders($data);

            $sql = "UPDATE {$dbTable} SET {$set} WHERE user_id = :uid"; 

            try
            {
                // Build the database statement
                $_stmt = $this->_dbConn->prepare($sql);
                $_stmt->bindValue(':uid',$id, PDO::PARAM_INT);

                foreach ($data as $field => $val) 
                {
                    if(is_int($val)){  
                        $_stmt->bindValue(':'.$field.'\', '.$val.', PDO::PARAM_INT');
                    }
                    else if(is_string($val)){
                        $_stmt->bindValue(':'.$field.'\', '.$val.', PDO::PARAM_STR');
                    }
                    else if(is_bool($val)){
                        $_stmt->bindValue(':'.$field.'\', '.$val.', PDO::PARAM_BOOL');
                    }
                    else if(is_null($val)){
                        $_stmt->bindValue(':'.$field.'\', '.$val="null".', PDO::PARAM_NULL');
                    }
                    else {
                        $_stmt->bindValue(':'.$field.'\', '.$val.', NULL');
                    }

                    $result = $_stmt->execute();
                    $num = $_stmt->rowCount();
                }

            }
            catch(PDOException $e)
            {
                die('Error!  The process failed while updating your record. <br /> Line #'.__LINE__ .' '.$e);
            }

            if ($result === true)
            {
                return true; 
            }               
        }
```

Comment: what database are you using behind all this? if it's mysql, you're passing in an incorrect date string for the logintime. if it's going into a datetime field, you'll end up with 0000-00-00 00:00:00 instead.

Answer (score 0):

Check your bindValue calls: You give 1 parameter (a long string). It needs at least two. Check all the '

for example, it should be:

```
$_stmt->bindValue(':'.$field, $val, PDO::PARAM_INT);
```

Comment: Could it be that this <code> $_stmt->bindValue(':uid',$id, PDO::PARAM_INT);</code> that is located above the “foreach ($data …” is not getting executed, since the <code> $result = $_stmt->execute();</code> is within the foreach function?  If that’s so, where is the best place to put it so as to get executed?

Comment: Here is the solution:  I by-passed the bindValue method just for testing and included the array directly into the execute function instead, and it introduced a new message:  'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[22001]: String data, right truncated: 1406 Data too long for column.  This message is a lot more explicit and I was able to resolve the issue by changing the value of VARCHAR to a new larger value from 25 to 35 in the DB table column. This resolved the issue after a couple of hours.  I hope this info can help some one else to same some time.